# How to convert a TIF file into a bmp file in C++ 98?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, c++

I am new in C++? How i can convert TIF file into a bmp file in C++ 98 without any library?
Here is the link i found with library ?[link](https://products.aspose.com/slides/cpp/conversion/tiff-to-bmp/)

Here is my code but it is giving me error.I have taken it from this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1300/CxImage) .

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>
class CxImage
 {

 protected:
 void* pDib;            //contains the header, the palette, the pixels
 BITMAPINFOHEADER head; //standard header
 CXIMAGEINFO info;      //extended information
 BYTE* pSelection;      //selected region
 BYTE* pAlpha;          //alpha channel
 CxImage** ppLayers;     //generic layers
 CxImage** ppFrames;     //frames for animation
 }
 
CxImage  image;
// bmp -> jpg


image.Load("https://icon-library.com/images/22224-tiger-icon_5825.tiff", CXIMAGE_FORMAT_TIF);
if (image.IsValid()){
    if(!image.IsGrayScale()) image.IncreaseBpp(24);
    image.SetJpegQuality(80);
    image.Save("C:\Users\hp\Desktop\extro\tiger-icon_5825.bmp",CXIMAGE_FORMAT_BMP);
}
// png -> tif


image.Load("https://icon-library.com/images/22224-tiger-icon_5825.tiff", CXIMAGE_FORMAT_TIF);
if (image.IsValid()){
    image.Save("C:\Users\hp\Desktop\extro\tiger-icon_5825.bmp",CXIMAGE_FORMAT_BMP);
}
```

Comment: Better ask this on stackoverflow.com/ and make sure you include the actual error you get.

Comment: Everyone here i going to say use GDAL - why rewrite a whole library?